# Vectorize iterative Python loop: c[i] = a[i] + b[i] * c[i-1]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have an iterative Python function:

```py
import pandas as pd


def calculate_result(foo: pd.Series, bar: pd.Series, baz: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    result = pd.Series(index=foo.index, dtype=float)
    result.iloc[0] = foo.iloc[0]

    for i in range(1, len(foo)):
        result.iloc[i] = bar.iloc[i] + baz.iloc[i] * result.iloc[i - 1]  # core iterative logic

    return result
```

The function has a loop with an iterative calculation. I'd like to vectorize the loop if possible for performance reasons because I need to use the function a lot. It is okay to use NumPy or Pandas or SciPy or anything similar.

Here is a sample result:

```py
>>> foo = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> bar = pd.Series([2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> baz = pd.Series([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> print(calculate_result(foo, bar, baz))

0      1.0
1      7.0
2     39.0
3    239.0
dtype: float64
```

I tried the following but it returns an incorrect result:

```py
def calculate_result_vectorized(foo: pd.Series, bar: pd.Series, baz: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    result = (baz.cumprod() * foo + bar.cumsum() * baz.cumprod().shift()).fillna(foo)
    result.iloc[0] = foo.iloc[0]
    return result
```

I am wondering if a clever combination of `cumprod` and `cumsum`, etc. may do the trick.

Comment: Are you sure your iterative formula is what you want? You are only using the first element of `foo` and its length. Also, the first elements of `baz` and `bar` are not used.

Comment: If your `b` variable were a constant, rather than a series, you could try using a singal processing approach (e.g. scipy's [filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) )

Comment: @Rob Those are good observations, but yes, I am sure. There is a lot more to a broad problem that has been intentionally left out. What remains is only the part that I could not vectorize. Note that the first few values in each series are effectively throwaways. In the real world problem, ultimately the result converges to useful values.

Comment: `numpy` 'vectorization' means using compiled methods and operators.  Most do 'parellel' actions in all (or subset of) elements.  `cumsum` and other `ufunc.accumulate` are the only  serial ones.

Comment: It is possible to vectorize using numpy operations, but it will require O(N^2) space. Probably the numba answer is then more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Lets define the logic using an optimized python function then compile it with `numba` to achieve `C` like speeds

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(x, y, z):
    r = x[0]
    yield r
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        r = y[i] + z[i] * r
        yield r

s = pd.Series(func(foo.values, bar.values, baz.values), foo.index)
```

Result

```
0      1
1      7
2     39
3    239
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Numba is interesting, but as a user it would be my responsibility to benchmark it before use, relative to CPython 3.11 or newer. As a user I could not automatically assume Numba to be performant. Before the benchmark, a warmup of 100 iterations should be sufficient for both Numba and CPython. I'd also want to similarly benchmark a Taichi implementation if possible.

Comment: Whether or not this is faster than proper vectorisation (I suspect it won't be), it isn't really what the OP asked for.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up using Numpy data structures with Cython v3. As for Numba, it's a complete disaster and failure due to various errors.